# Can the decay constant of a material be determined from it's activity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, radioactivity

From the wikipedia page for Caesium-137, it decays in $\beta, \gamma$ modes and with a specific activity of $3.215$ TBq per gram of caesium.

My line of reasoning was this: Using the decay equation $ N(t) = N_0e^{-\lambda t} $ and the relationship $t_{1/2} = \frac{\ln{2}}{\lambda} $ I could compute the decay constant $\lambda$.

With an initial gram of caesium, it has an atomic mass of $\mu = 137 g/mol$, 1 gram of caesium contains $\frac{1}{137} mol$ and therefore $\frac{1}{137} \cdot N_A$ particles which means $N_0 = 4.4 \cdot 10^{21}$ nuclei.
After one second $3.215 \cdot 10^{12}$ nuclei would decay as per the specific activity and therefore $N(1) = N_0 - 3.215 \cdot 10^{12} = N_0 e^{-\lambda}$. After calculations $e^{-\lambda} = \frac{4.39 \cdot 10^{21}}{4.4 \cdot 10^{21}}$ which gives $\lambda = 0.0022$ and $t_{1/2} = 315 s$ which is obviously wrong since the half-life is around 30 years for this isotope.

Where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: The half life is given in the wiki article.  Why not calculate decay constant from that?

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible to determine the half-life fron the source activity, I know how the decay constant and half-life are related

Comment: From $N(t)=N_0e^{-\lambda t}$ the activity is $A(t)=-\frac{dN}{dt}=\lambda N(t)$. So $\lambda=\frac{A(0)}{N(0)}$.